# implement 2 different listeners at the same class and adding at a swing component

Tags: java, listener

I would like to add 2 listeners at my `JList`: `MouseListener` and `KeyListener`; and use only `MouseClicked` et `Keypressed` but at the same class...

I know that I can do:

```
class FindSuggestionListener implements MouseListener, KeyListener
```

But it means that I have to do :

```
myJlist.addMouseListener(new findSuggestionListener());
myJlist.addKeyListener(new findSuggestionListener());
```

and so, add unimplemented methods...

Do you know how can I implement 2 different listeners at the same class and adding at a swing component?

thank you

Comment: Please tick my answer if it is correct :)

Comment: _Do you know how can I implement 2 different listeners at the same class and adding at a swing component?_ Do you mean something like: `myJList.addMouseAndKeyListener(new findSuggestionListener());` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your listener into a variable then add it to the JList

```
findSuggestionListener suggestionListener = new findSuggestionListener();
myJlist.addMouseListener(suggestionListener);
myJlist.addKeyListener(suggestionListener);
```